# Setting the Value for Arraylist of Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hello I want to Fill Up my Arraylist of Arraylist named as `QuestionIdList_Section`
and for that i have make the temp Arraylist named `QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp` that will be clear after adding into `QuestionIdList_Section`

My Code is as Below so that  you can understand how i have codded :

```
public static ArrayList<String> QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> QuestionIdList_Section = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp.add("Hello");
QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp.add("Hiii");

QuestionIdList_Section.add(0,QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp);

Log.i(TAG, "******Before " + QuestionIdList_Section);
Log.i(TAG, "******Before "+ QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp);

QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp.clear();

Log.i(TAG, "******After  " + QuestionIdList_Section);
Log.i(TAG, "******After " + QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp);
```

After Executing the Code i am getting Different Result for both Variable.

as Below :

```
******Before [[Hello, Hiiii]]
******Before [Hello, Hiiii]
******After [[]]
******After []
```

can some one Please Help me to Understand where i am lacking here. i want to clear temp arraylist so that i can put the different Values for `UESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp` so for second index of `QuestionIdList_Section` i will set the Value different.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you clear the QuestionIdList_Section?

Comment: use `QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp.remove(item)` instead of `QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp.clear();`

Comment: just change `QuestionIdList_Section.add(0,QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp);` to `QuestionIdList_Section.add(0,new ArrayList<String>(QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp));` and your code will work because you will need to copy ArrayList instead of passing reference before cleaning it

Comment: Hi, just as a hint, look at the naming conventions of java: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp` is just a reference.

So if you clear it, the value in `QuestionIdList_Section` will also be clear.

What you should do is

`QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp = new ArrayList<String>();`

instead of

`QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp.clear();`

Answer (score 2):

The `ArrayList` associated with `QuestionIdList_Section` holds a *reference* of the `ArrayList` associated with `QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp`.

Thus, when clearing the temp ArrayList, it will also reflect on the ArrayList which is in `QuestionIdList_Section`.

You might want to create a *new instance* of temp array and add it to the main array list as follows:

```
QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp = new ArrayList<String>();
QuestionIdList_Section.add(QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp);
```

After doing so, every element you add to `QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp` will be shown in thew second index of `QuestionIdList_Section`.

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the `QUESTION_ID_Of_SectionId_Temp` array which means it has no elements. The second "After" print displays it empty.

The first "After" displays the contents of the `QuestionIdList_Section` which still contains the `ArrayList` above, which is empty now.